# How To Set App Icon Using SmartFaceApp Studio After Getting License?

Tags: cross-platform, smartface.io

I want to Set App Icon(Project Icon) Using SmartFaceApp Studio After Getting License,could some one help with my Question,
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

Go in this path \resources\Images\android\drawable of your project_data folder you will see icon.png replace that with the icon of your app